# regular expression for finding out 'anything <script>anything</script> anything' anywhere in string

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation, server-side-validation

i am trying to find out scrip tag both open() and close() in my php string.Please find my code below

```
public function custom_xss_clean($str){
  if(!preg_match('/(<\/?)(script|html)(>*)/i', $str)){
       return true;
  } else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('custom_xss_clean','The %s field invalid');
    return false;
  }
}
```

This code is working fine in online tool but not in my code for string

`<script>alert(10)</script>`

I have tried so many pattern but no luck.Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. parsing html using a regex is generally not a very good idea and 2. you can also use javascript in html attributes so this is kind of pointless / not nearly enough.

Comment: thanks for quick reply Sahil but i am doing it for codeigniter validation.I have created a callback custom_xss_clean().Since CI is no longer support for XSS_CLEAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
preg_match('/<script>[a-zA-Z0-9 \. \n \t\r \* \\ \* ~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={}\[\]\'":;?\/><.,|]*<\/script>/', $str);
```

Am Tested also you can check live https://regex101.com/r/ih2C3F/1/

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to get everything between script tags?

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U","<script>example: </script><div align=left>this is a test</div>",$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    echo '<pre>',
    print_r($out);
```

if you are looking for xss_clean in codeigniter then follow this link [click](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)